# When ORA-01830 error occur?

Tags: oracle

I need an explanation on the following issue:
I'm inserting some values in a table and for a `TIMESTAMP(6)` column the value
`11-JAN-16 03.04.30.944265000` throws the error mentioned in title.

For some other values it doesn't throw any error as for instance:

```
10-JAN-16 05.15.15.063826000
10-JAN-16 05.10.45.039946000
10-JAN-16 05.09.45.060794000
```

I know i should not rely on implicit cast from varchar to timestamp, that's why i'll use the conversion:

```
to_timestamp(column, 'DD-Mon-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF)
```

Please let me know why and when this error occur. Thank you!
A

Comment: Do you get the error when you use `TO_TIMESTAMP(column, 'DD-Mon-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF')`?

Comment: Are you getting the error when you insert that value (if so please show the exact command you use), or when you query it - if the latter are you using `to_timestamp()` in the query? The call you show is against `column`, and if that is *already* a timestamp that is not correct. It's hard to tell quite what you are doing though.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a test environment based on your requirement. Take a look below:

```
     CREATE TABLE SCOTT.TEST
        (
          A  TIMESTAMP(6)
        );


    SQL> Insert into SCOTT.TEST (A)
     Values(TO_TIMESTAMP('01-10-16 05:15:15.063826000','fmMMfm-fmDDfm-YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'));  2  

    1 row created.

    SQL> Insert into SCOTT.TEST (A)
     Values(TO_TIMESTAMP('01-10-16 05.10.45.039946000','fmMMfm-fmDDfm-YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'));  2  

    1 row created.

    SQL> Insert into SCOTT.TEST (A)
     Values(TO_TIMESTAMP('01-10-16 05.09.45.060794000','fmMMfm-fmDDfm-YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'));  2  

    1 row created.

    SQL> COMMIT;

    Commit complete.

    SQL> select * from test;

    A
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    10-JAN-16 05.15.15.063826 AM
    10-JAN-16 05.10.45.039946 AM
    10-JAN-16 05.09.45.060794 AM
```

-- Using another format mask

```
SQL> Insert into SCOTT.TEST (A)
 Values(TO_TIMESTAMP('10-JAN-16 05.15.15.063826000','fmDDfm-fmMONfm-YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'));SQL>   2  

1 row created.

SQL> Insert into SCOTT.TEST (A)
 Values(TO_TIMESTAMP('10-JAN-16 05.10.45.039946000','fmDDfm-fmMONfm-YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'));  2  

1 row created.

SQL> Insert into SCOTT.TEST (A)
 Values(TO_TIMESTAMP('10-JAN-16 05.09.45.060794000','fmDDfm-fmMONfm-YYYY fmHH12fm:MI:SS.FF AM'));  2  

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from test;

A
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-JAN-16 05.15.15.063826 AM
10-JAN-16 05.10.45.039946 AM
10-JAN-16 05.09.45.060794 AM
10-JAN-16 05.15.15.063826 AM
10-JAN-16 05.10.45.039946 AM
10-JAN-16 05.09.45.060794 AM

6 rows selected.
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

CAUSE

You tried to enter a date value, but the date entered did not match the date format.

Comment: No, the error occured before adding the to_timestamp conversion and i want to know why for some other records worked before adding it. Thanks!